# samples are uniformly located on a circle in matlab

Tags: matlab-figure, data-generation

I want to simulate data in Matlab with this condition:

> Samples are uniformly located on a circle of radius of 3. A normal noise with a variance of 0.05 is added to the X and Y coordinates.

And figure of this data is here:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

thank
i arrive to my answer:)
below code is my answer:

```
ang=linspace(0,2*pi,200);
xp=(3+.05*randn(1,200)).*cos(ang);
yp=(3+.05*randn(1,200)).*sin(ang);
scatter(xp,yp,'r+')
```